# UTF8 word contains mixed Japanese and english character. How to identify which character is Japanese and which is English?

Tags: java, c++, c

I have an UTF8 encoded string which contains Japanese and Roman characters. 
I want to identify which characters are Japanese and which are Roman? How to identify?

Comment: Maybe something with regex: `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: FWIW, there's an oddity to deal with, which is full-width Roman characters. You have to decide whether you want to consider those as Japanese or as Roman, it might depend what the purpose is. For example, if the purpose is to identify whether the text is mostly in the Japanese language, you'd want to treat them as Roman. If the purpose is to identify whether the string can be printed using a Latin-only font, they're Japanese (although they could be mapped to their "normal" equivalents).

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for the Unicode "Script" property.  I recommend the ICU library.

From: http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uscript_8h.html

```
UScriptCode     uscript_getScript (UChar32 codepoint, UErrorCode *err)
Gets the script code associated with the given codepoint.
```

The result will tell you the script of the character.  Here are some of the possible constants returned:

- USCRIPT_JAPANESE (Not sure what's in this category...)
- USCRIPT_HIRAGANA (Japanese kana)
- USCRIPT_KATAKANA (Japanese kana)
- USCRIPT_HAN (Japanese kanji)
- USCRIPT_LATIN
- USCRIPT_COMMON (spaces and punctuation that are common to all scripts)

LibICU is available for Java, C, and C++.  You will need to parse the Unicode code points out to use the function.

**Alternative:** You can also use a Unicode regular expression, although very few engines support this syntax (Perl does...)  This PCRE will match strings of text that is *definitely* Japanese, but it will not get everything.

```
/\p{Katakana,Hiragana,Han}+/
```

You have to be careful when you parse these things out because Japanese text will often include romaji or numerals inline.  A glance at ja.wikipedia.org will quickly confirm this.

Answer (score 6):

You can determine Unicode [category](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/rev2/UnicodeCategories.html), in Java with [Character.getType()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType%28int%29). For Japanese it will be Lo, for latin characters Ll, Lu.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Unicode code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/), japanese characters can be Hiragana, Katakana and Ideographs. These sets have defined start and end positions so you could create a function that checks if a character is within these limits.

```
bool isJapanese(wchar_t w)
{
   // Hiragana...
   if (w >= 0x3041 && w <= 0x309F)
      return true;
   // Do the same for the other sets
   ...
   return false; 
}
```

Similarly you can implement an `isRoman` function...

Comment: an UTF-8 encoded string does not use a wide-char type. and the UTF-8 encoding is more complicated than just comparing a value...

Comment: I assume has has converted his UTF8 string to a wstring. http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/ supports this conversion.

Comment: you shall not "assume"... he did not say he did it. however your pointer to the utfcpp library is of particular interest to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care for accuracy, just check the first byte of each UTF-8 sequence: If the sequence has length <= 2 (ie first byte <= 0xDF), assume roman characters, otherwise japanese.

Personally, I'd probably just [use Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#%2aScripts%2a).

Comment: also, it is worth having a look at the unicode definition and see in which range the japanese characters fall. then differentiating japanese and english characters should not be difficult and will be accurate.

Comment: @Adrien: the distinction by sequence length is accurate if all you care about is Latin and the various Japanese scripts; however, other blocks will also be wrongly identified as Latin (eg Arabic) or Japanese as we basically just split the codepoint range at 0x07FF (the largest codepoint encoded as a 2-byte sequence)

Comment: Good idea, there are only 2 things to be sure of. The Latin text should not contain characters from the LATIN EXTENDED ADDITIONAL range (U+1E00-U1EFF) and it should not contain general punctuations (U+2000-U+206F) and quotes, em-dash and hyphens are not that rare.